# How can I simplify this jQuery JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda new to coding with jQuery / JavaScript. I've managed to write the code below but I think there is a much easier way to write it down. Is there somebody who can show me how?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn_home").click(function(){
$("#article1").fadeIn();
$("#article2").fadeOut();
$("#article3").fadeOut();
$("#article4").fadeOut();

$("#blended").fadeOut();
$("#contact").fadeOut();
});

$(".btn_prt").click(function(){
$("#article1").fadeOut();
$("#article2").fadeIn();
$("#article3").fadeOut();
$("#article4").fadeOut();


$("#over").fadeIn();
$("#blended").fadeOut();
$("#contact").fadeOut();
});

$(".btn_blog").click(function(){
$("#article1").fadeOut();
$("#article2").fadeOut();
$("#article3").fadeIn();
$("#article4").fadeOut();

$("#over").fadeOut();
$("#blended").fadeIn();
$("#contact").fadeOut();
});

$(".btn_abt").click(function(){
$("#article1").fadeOut();
$("#article2").fadeOut();
$("#article3").fadeOut();
$("#article4").fadeIn();

$("#over").fadeOut();
$("#blended").fadeOut();
$("#contact").fadeIn();
}); 
});
```

Comment: Post the question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: In addition to this not being posted in the right place, you would also need to show the HTML and explain what this is supposed to achieve.

Comment: I did not know there was a special section for codereview. Won't happen again :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is code duplication. You need to use a function with a parameter to help with that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn_prt").click(function(){
        fadeAllBut("#article2, #over");
    });

    $(".btn_blog").click(function(){
        fadeAllBut("#article3, #blended");
    });

    $(".btn_abt").click(function(){
        fadeAllBut("#article4, #contact");
    }); 
});

function fadeAllBut(itemsToFadeIn) {
    $(".fades").fadeOut();
    $(itemsToFadeIn).stop().fadeIn();
}
```

Of course, you would need to give the CSS class `fades`  to all the items you would like to fade in or out.

Comment: Thanks! That looks pretty clean to me and it works perfect!

Answer (score 10):

You can combine items:

```
$("#foo, #bar, #baz").fadeIn();
```

or you may use classes

```
$('.notneeded').fadeOut();
```

Comment: While you are right, simply giving a class to items to fade out will not help because they sometimes need to fade in as well. Also combining the tags is a little shorter but in essence that does not make his code any more structured.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document)
.ready(function () {
$(".btn_home")
    .click(function () {
    $("#article1")
        .fadeIn(), $("#article2")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article3")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article4")
        .fadeOut(), $("#blended")
        .fadeOut(), $("#contact")
        .fadeOut()
}), $(".btn_prt")
    .click(function () {
    $("#article1")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article2")
        .fadeIn(), $("#article3")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article4")
        .fadeOut(), $("#over")
        .fadeIn(), $("#blended")
        .fadeOut(), $("#contact")
        .fadeOut()
}), $(".btn_blog")
    .click(function () {
    $("#article1")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article2")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article3")
        .fadeIn(), $("#article4")
        .fadeOut(), $("#over")
        .fadeOut(), $("#blended")
        .fadeIn(), $("#contact")
        .fadeOut()
}), $(".btn_abt")
    .click(function () {
    $("#article1")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article2")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article3")
        .fadeOut(), $("#article4")
        .fadeIn(), $("#over")
        .fadeOut(), $("#blended")
        .fadeOut(), $("#contact")
        .fadeIn()
})
})
```